# JODConverter: "could not obtain service: com.sun.star.ucb.FileContentProvider"

Tags: java, linux, process, jodconverter, libreoffice

I write java-application, which show documents as web-pages; to convert it from any format to HTML I use JODConverter and I have some bug:

I try to run soffice as service by this procedure:

```
System.getRuntime().exec(
"soffice -headless -nofirststartwizard 
-accept=\"socket,host=my_ip,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.Service\"");
```

It creates process:

```
panzersoldat@panzertank:~$ ps ax|grep soffice
 3514 ?        Sl     0:01 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin -headless -nofirststartwizard -accept="socket,host=my_ip,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.Service" -splash-pipe=5
```

And when I try to convert any document I get this error: http://pastebin.com/mDwsZMhu

But then I run soffice from bash script:

```
soffice -headless -nofirststartwizard -accept="socket,host=my_ip,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.Service"
```

and try to convert document, all working correctly:

```
02.05.2011 11:15:19 com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.AbstractOpenOfficeConnection getService
INFO: trying to (re)connect
02.05.2011 11:15:19 com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.AbstractOpenOfficeConnection connect
INFO: connected
```

I thought that this error may be caused by iptables, and add rule:

```
-A INPUT -i ppp0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8100 -j ACCEPT
```

But this error still continue.

Have any idea?